# Hex to Decimal Conversion Error

Tags: android, android-bluetooth, hex

I have a byte array -

```
byte[] byteArr = new byte[] { (byte)0x00 , (byte)0xF0 , (byte)0x03 };
```

I am just getting each one,

```
Integer byte1 = Integer.valueOf(byteArr[0]);
Integer byte2 = Integer.valueOf(byteArr[1]);
Integer byte3 = Integer.valueOf(byteArr[2]);

String pgnString = byte1.toString() + byte2.toString() + byte3.toString();
```

And my output is: `0-163`

But I can see the correct output should be: `61443`

Link--- http://www.binaryhexconverter.com/hex-to-decimal-converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats because bytes are signed. `(byte)0xF0` is actually the same as `(byte)-16`.

To convert as unsigned quantity you can mask the lower 8 bits:

```
int byte1 = byteArr[0] & 0xff;
int byte2 = byteArr[1] & 0xff;
int byte3 = byteArr[2] & 0xff;

String pgnString = String.valueOf(byte1 * 0x10000 + byte2 * 0x100 + byte3);
```

Comment: Ok but now I am getting `02403` but not `61443` as is coming from converter.

Comment: See edit. you must take into account that the bytes have different weight.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to go through them one at a time, you can use `ByteBuffer` to convert to another base.

```
byte[] byteArr = new byte[] { (byte)0x00 , (byte)0x00 , (byte)0xF0 , (byte)0x03 };
int value = ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArr).getInt();
// value = 61443
```

Note: the `byte[]` must have a length of 4 (or call `getInt()` for each 4 byte part).